# Quirky Google Chrome Beta/Dev channel behavior persists even after uninstalling and reverting to stable

Tags: google-chrome, browser

We have several FogBugz customers who have [reported an error](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/9079) in Chrome where if the user presses `Enter` in an edit box, the edit box will lose focus and they'll have to click back in to the box for it to gain focus.

All users reporting this error (that we're aware of) have mentioned using Chrome Beta. We don't support Chrome Beta, so we advise downgrading to Chrome Stable. We can't repro the bug on Stable.

One of our users uninstalled Beta and installed Stable. He tried again and was again able to reproduce the bug, even after clearing his browser's cache (with no tabs open) on Stable.

In a related scenario, another member of our team noticed quirky behavior in Chrome persisting when switching from Chrome Dev to Chrome Stable. He also cleared his cache and noticed the behavior persisting in Chrome.

Have any other web developers experienced this kind of behavior in Chrome with customers using their web applications? If so, is there anything you can do within your application to help users and/or do you know of a way to completely "wipe" Chrome and revert it to the Stable version? (at the moment, the latter option is preferred).

Answer (score 1):

Moving up versions should be okay, since Chrome is designed to upgrade smoothly.

Moving down versions (like dev to stable) can be problematic, since there's really no provision for older versions of Chrome to understand new versions of the user directory.

If you want a fresh start, you can wipe your entire [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). However, since this directory contains everything about the user (caches, saved passwords, apps/extensions, etc), **all of that will be lost**.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll suggest wiping the user data directory to see if that helps.

Comment: I imagine that users *think* that they can easily switch between stable/beta/dev at any time. Power users and devs get excited about using the latest Google tools, but aren't aware that it could permanently effect their experience on every web app that they use.